# Encoding RTFD for XML

Tags: xml, cocoa, rtf, nsattributedstring

I need to embed RTFD strings (typically short) in an XML file.

```
XMLWriter writer(...)

NSAttributedString *ns=.....
NSRange all=NSMakeRange(0,[s length]);
NSData *rtfd=[s RTFDFromRange:all documentAttributes:nil];

writer.Write(rtfd);
```

RTFD gives us no assurance (as I understand it -- I can't seem to find the standard doc) that the data bytes will be safe even as CDATA -- or indeed representable as UTF8. How should I encode them?

Objectives include:

- human readability
- compactness
- speed of encoding and decoding

though clearly compromise may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
This really only works with RTF, not RTFD. That is, if `[ns containsAttachments]`, it will likely fail to create the `rtfString` at the end.

---

You can specify some options when creating the RTFD to get it in UTF8 encoding.

This code is working well for us (although we're using property list serialization):

```
NSAttributedString *ns = ...;
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *rtfString = nil;
NSData *rtfdData = [ns dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [ns length])
                   documentAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       NSRTFDTextDocumentType, NSDocumentTypeDocumentOption,
                                       [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding], NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute,
                                           nil]
                                error:&error];
if (error == nil) {
    rtfString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData: rtfdData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Then, `writer.Write(rtfString);`

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, initWithData: specifies the encoding in which the DATA is encoded, before translation to Unicode.  So this won't work if, for example, an image attachement has a byte sequence that's illegal for UTF8.

Comment: `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute` is set to `NSUTF8StringEncoding` when the data is created, so the data IS encoded in UTF8. That is, any such byte sequences get flattened out during the creation of the data.

Comment: I dont think this will work: the NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute describes the encoding of the document being read: "These option keys are recognized for importing documents using initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:, initWithHTML:options:documentAttributes:, initWithURL:options:documentAttributes:error:, or the readFrom... methods (such as readFromData:options:documentAttributes:) implemented by NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: And in my experiment, in point of fact, it didnt work; the rtfdData is created, but the NSString conversion fails. (I believe you should check that rtfString is nil *before* checking error, btw, since error is undefined on success.)

Comment: In the case of `dataFromRange`, the supplied attributes dictionary is specifying the desired format. The same keys are also used for importing documents, but in this case the doc is being generated. I'd be interested to see the test case that fails, as this code is more-or-less copied from a shipping product.

Comment: Have you tested with embedded jpegs?  (Sorry for the comment dialog -- these little comments are not very helpful for situations like this).  I'd be DELIGHTED to take this to email if that would be better. bernstein@eastgate.com

Comment: After online discussion, Brian and I have concluded that this is a dead end **if** the rtfd has attachments.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there's not a very good answer.

The `description` method for NSData, used by the property-list serializer, writes a hex dump.  That's reliable and XML safe, but not compact or legible.

I'm currently using Base64 encoded, which is not compact (but better than hexadecimal) and not legible, but also perfectly safe for XML.

ISTM that UTF8 should lend itself easily to a Base256-37=Base219 encoding, where we omit the control characters 00-31 and also the characters that are special in XML ( < > " ' & ).  Am I missing something, or is there a good name for this?